# using fancybox set height and width

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i am new to j query, it is cool, but i am glued to the ceiling on how to add width and height to a iframe generated after click, using this code: all suggestions would be great and thanks in advance
Khadija

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 })
 .height = '600px';
```

Comment: When you say `iframe` we understand that you are using fancybox to open an external html page or document, aren't you?

Answer (score 18):

You must set **autoSize** to false

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({'width':400,
                         'height':300,
                         'autoSize' : false});
```

Comment: 'type': 'inline',
'autoDimensions': false,
'width': 600,
'height': 600,

Comment: Worked for me: apparently autoSize defaults to false, as I deleted the line setting auotSize to false, then set my height and width - worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

To initialize the fancybox popup for the usage of an iframe, limited to a certain width and height, you need at least three parameters:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'width'  : 600,           // set the width
    'height' : 600,           // set the height
    'type'   : 'iframe'       // tell the script to create an iframe
  });
});
```

You can read all about the available options at the [FancyBox API Page](http://fancybox.net/api).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({"width":400,"height":300});
 })
```

Comment: Additionally you have to set either the parameter `'type':'iframe'` or add the class `iframe` for fancybox v1.3.4 or class `fancybox.iframe` for fancybox v2.x to the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Use code given below:

```
fancybox({
    afterLoad  : function () {
        $.extend(this, {
            aspectRatio : false,
            type    : 'html',
            width   : '90%',
            height  : '90%',
            content : '<div class="fancybox-image" style="background-image:url(' + this.href + '); background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:100%;width:100%;" /></div>'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code set size of fancy dynamic @ run time only you have to pass height & width along with page url,to whom you want to set

Eg:  demo.aspx
     //this statement calls fancy function which is present in your main page

```
       window.parent.SetFancySizeDynamic(YourPageUrl,300,200)

  MainPage.aspx
```

// just add this function in your main page

```
    function SetFancySizeDynamic(fbHref, fbWidth, fbHeight) {

        $.fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'overlayColor': '#ccc',
            'type': 'iframe',
            'href': fbHref,
            'width': fbWidth,
            'height': fbHeight

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to set autoSize to false, worked for me

$(".fancybox").fancybox({'width':400,
                         'height':300,
                         'autoSize' : false});

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){     
            $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lightwindow").fancybox({
                    minWidth: 250,
                    width: 250,
                    minHeight: 500,
                    height: 500,
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'autoDimensions': false,
                    'scrolling'     : 'no',
                    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                    'transitionOut' : 'none',
                    'type': 'iframe'                   
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**With iframe**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            width:600,
            height:400,
            type: 'iframe',
            href  : 'url_here'
       });
     })
```

**Without iframe**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width:600,
        height:400,
        autoDimensions: false,
   });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me was with *preload = false* on the iframe:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    iframe : {
        css : {
            height : '1000px',
        },
        preload : false
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this css :)**

```
.fancybox-overlay .fancybox-skin {
   max-width: 900px !important;
   margin: auto;
}

.fancybox-overlay .fancybox-inner {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fancybox-overlay .fancybox-skin {
   margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution. Note that i am using **data-type=ajax** . I checked all above solutions but not work for me then i did some RND then i find a solution. it is common for all. **activeVehicleCurrentMonth** is div that being show on pop-up. by that class i am defining **Width**.

```
 $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
            afterShow: function( instance, slide ) {
                $("#activeVehicleCurrentMonth").css("transition-duration",'1000ms').css("width",'90%');
            }
 })
```

**Another Solution** is

```
 <a id="action-issue-fBox" data-fancybox data-type="ajax" autocomplete="off"
    data-width="1500" data-height="400"
      data-src="{{ route('active-vehicle-popup-current-month') }}">Action Issues
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have still issues

```
            width      = current.width,
            height     = current.height,
```

modify it in jquery.fancybox.js

Comment: not the one who downvoted but this isn't a good idea, as it's changing it globally which I'd guess isn't what most people are after.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying or adding this line:

`.fancybox-content{width:360px !important;height:400px !important;}`

Comment: it is not work.

Comment: Not sure how you tried. it is working fine for me.