# How do I set Fancybox Height and Width as a Percentage with Dynamic HTML?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, overlay

I'm currently using Fancybox 2.1.2 and would like to know how I can create an overlay on my web application.  I can set the height and width of the the popup (note... this is not an iframe) and it will adjust with static values, but I would like to be able to set the height to a dynamic value like 80%.  I can't seem to get this to work though.  When I load fancybox with no height or width set I get this really small lightbox and it does not go to the default values of 600px for height and 800px for width.  Is this because I am adding in the HTML for the lightbox dynamically through the content method? I am also adding in content dynamically after the lightbox is done loading. The goal is to create a full overlay for my app with setting height as a percentage.

The current code is:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    'content' : '\
                  <div class="light_box upload">\
                      <div class="title">Your Photos of '+city+'</div>\
                      <div>\
                          <div class="uploadifive-queue" id="uploadifive-upload_photo-queue"></div>\
                      </div>\
                  </div>'
});
```

And my CSS is:

```
.light_box.upload{
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306587/using-fancybox-set-height-and-width/71508335#71508335 here I have motioned best solution.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can turn off "autoSize" and then set width as "auto":

```
$.fancybox.open({
    content  : '<div id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</div>',
    autoSize : false,
    width    : "auto",
    height   : "80%"
});​
```

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2VmrG/

Comment: This didn't work for me...  but what did is adding your max height and width like this...  ```<a ....   data-width="1140" data-height="760">```  The library handles the resizing on smaller devices.