# JQuery - Trying to resize a Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to resize a fancybox lightbox so that it doesn't take up the whole entire page. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(.fancybox.open({
        autoDimensions: false,
        width: "60%"
    });​
</script>
```

But that doesn't do anything. Is there anything wrong with this code specifically?

Comment: The fancy box probably has an id or some kind of tag that it can be referred to, correct? The code you've posted won't change your fancybox because it doesn't address a particular (or even class of) item.

Comment: I updated the code, but still nothing. I feel like I'm missing some quotations or parantheses or something.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you, if you want to use CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755991/jquery-change-fancybox-width

Comment: Tried that too, so far nothing. Hmm. This is quite the predicament.

Comment: What version of fancybox?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.fancybox').css("width", "60%");
</script>
```

You may need to do this after the box is opened, if the box attributes are created when the box is first opened.

It looks like you are trying to do some function call, but I don't think that's needed. However, if you do need that, try using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.fancybox').open(function(){
        width: "60%"
    });
</script>
```

Or, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755991/jquery-change-fancybox-width) based on @Xetnus suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately neither of those worked either. I definitely need to call a variable called autoSize and set it to false from what I understand.

Comment: If all else fails, you can go into the js file for the fancybox and modify there. However, please use caution in doing this as this will modify EVERY fancybox. Modifying the js file isn't advised, but if you are only planning on using a couple fancy boxes, and they all need to be the same size, this may be a valid option for you.