# Fancybox set height and width attributes for some image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'am using fancybox and I would like to set for some image the width and height.
It's possible to do this?

All suggestions would be great and thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using fancybox set height and width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306587/using-fancybox-set-height-and-width)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, that other question is about using fancybox with the iframe type, and this one is about the image type. The solutions for iframe type did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to set width and height for the "image" type in fancybox, this worked for me:

```
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
arrows : true,
autoSize: false,
fitToView: false,
afterLoad: function(){
    this.width = 960;
    this.height = 540;
    }  
}
});
```

Where you change 960 and 540 for any value you need, or you can do a javascript calculation in the function as well. If you want to run code for certain image, you can check the ID or another attribute of the current element. For example if this is your html:

```
<div class="photo-block fancybox" id="image1" data-fancybox-group="group" href="/image.jpg" title="Image description to show">
<div class="photo-block-img"><img src="/image.jpg"/></div>
<div class="photo-block-text">Some text that shows in here</div></div><div class="photo-block fancybox" id="image2" data-fancybox-group="group" href="/image.jpg" title="Image description to show">
<div class="photo-block-img"><img src="/image.jpg"/></div>
<div class="photo-block-text">Some text that shows in here</div>
```

Then you can do as follows to only apply this to ID "image2", inside the afterLoad function:

```
if($(this.element).attr('id') == 'image2'){
    this.width=960;
    this.height=540;
}
```

I had to use "afterLoad" and not "beforeLoad" as I saw in answers for the "iframe" type. beforeLoad did not have any effect for the image type, but afterLoad worked.