# jQuery fancybox with thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, fancybox, elevatezoom

I'm using fancybox (2.15) and elevatezoom (3.0.8) that come with Magento 1.9.2.4, to zoom the main image and create a fancybox gallery with the other images of the gallery. Fancybox is opened when clicking on the main image.

What i need, is to use the thumbnail helper to navigate the thumbnails while the fancybox is open, but the problem is that I'm not able to initialize it in the easiest and suggested way, like

`$(selector).fancybox({config});`

and the way i'm using has no effect on the fancybox appearance.

This is the code i'm using

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if($('.thumb-link').size() == 0){
                var ez = $('.gallery-image.visible').first().data('zoom-image');
            }else{
                var ez =  $(".thumb-link");
            }

            $.fancybox({
                'width':400,
                'height': 500,

                helpers : {
                    title   : {
                        type: 'outside'
                    },
                     thumbs : {
                       width    : 50,
                       height   : 50
                    }
                }
            });

            $(".gallery-image.visible").bind("click", function(e) {  
                $.fancybox(ez);
                return false;
            });

        });
```

where `.gallery-image.visible` is the main image and the `.thumb-link` are the thumbnails in my Html.

Following other questions like this one [using fancybox set height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306587/using-fancybox-set-height-and-width)

but I actually get not visible effect on the fancybox.

Is there a different way to re-initialize fancybox configurations before calling it effectively?

**EDIT:**
Actually I changed my code in this way:

```
var fancyConfig =  {'width' : 200, 'height': 300,...};

            $(".gallery-image.visible").bind("click", function(e) {  
                $.fancybox(ez, fancyConfig);
                return false;
            });
```

and I can see some effects but no trace of thumbs....I included and can see the proper libraries for fancybox thumbnails helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out that using the libraries used in the fiddle and not the ones I was loading in my server, makes the scripts compatible and it works. 
So in this way it works:

```
var fancyConfig =  {
            helpers : {
                thumbs  : {
                    width   : 50,
                    height  : 50
                }
            }
        };
        $(".gallery-image").click(function(e) {  
            $.fancybox(ez, fancyConfig);
            return false;
        });
```

and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4s7hLdyf/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      if($('.thumb-link').size() == 0){
          var ez = $('.gallery-image.visible').first().data('zoom-image');
      }else{
          var ez =  $(".thumb-link");
      }

      var fancyConfig =  {
              'speedIn' : 1000,
              'speedOut' : 1000,
              helpers : {
                  title   : {
                      type: 'outside'
                  },
                  thumbs  : {
                      width   : 50,
                      height  : 50
                  }
              }
          };
      $(".gallery-image.visible").bind("click", function(e) {  
          $.fancybox(ez, fancyConfig);
          return false;
      });

  });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.product-image-thumbs li:first-child {
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.product-image-thumbs li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.product-image-thumbs a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.product-image-thumbs a img{
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-image-gallery .gallery-image {
    display: none;
}
.product-image-gallery .gallery-image.visible {
    display: block;
}

.product-img-box .product-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 750px;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="product-img-box">
  <div class="product-image product-image-zoom zoom-available">
      <div class="product-image-gallery">
          <img id="image-main"
               class="gallery-image visible"
               src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/111755/pexels-photo-111755.jpeg"
               alt="custom-alt"
               title="img-title" 
                data-zoom-image="https://static.pexels.com/photos/111755/pexels-photo-111755.jpeg" />

              <img id="image-main"
                   class="gallery-image"
               src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/111755/pexels-photo-111755.jpeg" />
              <img id="image-0"
                   class="gallery-image"
                   src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/67832/sunrise-sky-blue-sunlight-67832.jpeg" />
               <img id="image-1"
                   class="gallery-image"
                   src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/majestic-sunrise-over-the-mountains-picture-id185067762?k=6&m=185067762&s=612x612&w=0&h=QFGIsuncZGtiLeCQk6aMR14nOUrJNsFmXgpbT7oEU0c=" />
              <img id="image-2"
                   class="gallery-image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/111755/pexels-photo-111755.jpeg" />

      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="more-views">
   <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
        <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" title="my-title" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-image-index="2" href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/111755/pexels-photo-111755.jpeg">
                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/111755/pexels-photo-111755.jpeg" alt="custom-alt" />
            </a>
            <a class="thumb-link" title="my-title" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-image-index="0" href="https://static.pexels.com/photos/67832/sunrise-sky-blue-sunlight-67832.jpeg">
                <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/67832/sunrise-sky-blue-sunlight-67832.jpeg" alt="custom-alt" />
            </a>
            <a class="thumb-link" title="my-title" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-image-index="1" href="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/majestic-sunrise-over-the-mountains-picture-id185067762?k=6&m=185067762&s=612x612&w=0&h=QFGIsuncZGtiLeCQk6aMR14nOUrJNsFmXgpbT7oEU0c=g">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/majestic-sunrise-over-the-mountains-picture-id185067762?k=6&m=185067762&s=612x612&w=0&h=QFGIsuncZGtiLeCQk6aMR14nOUrJNsFmXgpbT7oEU0c=" alt="custom-alt" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this piece of code does not do anything, I do not see any selector or collection of objects here:

```
$.fancybox({
  'width':400,
  'height': 500,

  helpers : {
    title   : {
      type: 'outside'
    },
    thumbs : {
      width    : 50,
      height   : 50
    }
  }
});
```

I think you should replace `$.fancybox(ez);` with `$.fancybox.open(ez, {config});`

Comment: yes you're almost right and if you look at my edited code, you can see I was trying to do almost the same you suggested (just invert the order of arguments), but i got still no trace of the thumbs.

Comment: If you would provide a jsfiddle/codepen demo, that would help a lot.

Comment: mmmm actually i created a fiddle and in the fiddle the updated code seems to work... the problem is that it doesn't work in my server, and with magento is always difficult to understand why.... here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4s7hLdyf/